# Ubuntu 17.04 no plymouth during boot

Tags: boot, drivers, 17.04, plymouth

I have a **Nvidia Gtx 970** GPU and an **Intel Core i7 3770** CPU.

I cannot see the plymouth during startup. The only thing that appear is a *purple screen*, followed by a *black screen* and than the *lock screen* is loaded.

*Other solutions to the plymouth problem seems like they only work partially (no plymouth during black screen) or they are outdated because of some system directory changes. That's why this question is not a duplicate.*

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Yes nvdia drivers are installed and currently used.